# Sequences: how to prove it is crescent and calculate the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble with this kind of exercises:

> Consider the sequence defined by 
>   $ x_1= 1, $ 
>   $x_{n+1} = \frac {2x_n+3}{4} $
>   Prove that the sequence is crescent and that $x_n < 3/2 $ for all $n$ belonging to $\bf N$.

I'm really having trouble with this. I tried to do $x_{n+1} - x_n$ but I don't get to a real number... What am I doing wrong? Also, can someone give an hint on how to calculate the limit?

Thanks!

Comment: crescent = "increasing" in English.

Comment: At first, show the inequality using induction. To show that this sequence is increasing -
**Hint:** combine $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}x_n + \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{2} > x_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Each $x_{n+1}$ is the arithmetic mean between $x_n$ and $3/2$. You start with $x_1=1$, then conclude.